# Searching Date From DateTime table

Tags: php, search, boolean

I have code that to search the date Between start to from date

My Database field is like this:

> ==============================================
>
> id |    Userid        |  receivedDate
>
> ==============================================
>
> 1  |     abc          | 2013-07-10 14:07:40
>
> 2  |     abc          | 2013-07-15 16:27:04
>
> 3  |     rty          | 2013-07-10 16:27:04
>
> 4  |     rty          | 2013-07-16 16:07:04
>
> 5  |     abc          | 2013-07-25 11:07:04

Examples Database:

My Search Function is Like This

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM visitdate WHERE id <> ''";

if(isset($dateFrom) && $dateFrom !=""){
$sql_dateFrom= $sql_dateFrom." AND receivedDate='".$dateFrom."'";}

if(isset($dateTo) && $dateTo !=""){
    $sql_dateTo= $sql_dateTo." BETWEEN receivedDate='".$dateTo."'";}

    $query = $query.$sql_dateFrom.$sql_dateTo;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row['Userid'];
    }
```

Then this is my samples HTML Form:

```
<form name="form" type="post">
<input type="text" name="dateFrom">
<input type="text" name="dateTo">
<input type="submit" value="Searh">
</form>
```

***PROBLEM IS:***
How to display whole data from that users base on selected date. Thanks

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Try using `SQL INNER JOINS` and also use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` if you want to migrate later on MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: do you want to show data from one date to another..??

Comment: your question is not clear. sorry

Comment: Hi, yes... I mean let say i search DateFrom = 2013-07-10 TO 2013-07-25.. It show all data from date between... but, my mysql have time. error appear during searching... because the timestamps

Answer (score 0):

Try to build this query

```
 "SELECT * FROM visitdata WHERE id <> '' AND receivedDate >= '" . $dateFrom  . "' AND receivedDate <= '" . . "'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query. I already try this before. It is only show the selecting date and not showing the Between dateFrom to dateTo data.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the user input to a time stamp 1st and compare using your mysql something like this

`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(receivedDate,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM mytable`

Comment: Okay. I am trying... Thanks Friends

Answer (score 0):

Try building your query this way, using the mysql date function will cast your datetime fields to date fields.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM visitdate WHERE id <> ''";

if(isset($dateFrom) && $dateFrom !=""){
    $sql_dateFrom= $sql_dateFrom." AND date(receivedDate)>='".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom))."'";
}

if(isset($dateTo) && $dateTo !=""){
    $sql_dateTo= $sql_dateTo." AND date(receivedDate)<='".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateTo))."'";
}


$query = $query.$sql_dateFrom.$sql_dateTo;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Userid'];
}
```

This will allow for four possible cases

1. User Specifies start and end date, will get the records between inclusively
2. User Specifies a start date only, will get records for that date and later
3. User Specifies a end date only, will get records for that date and before
4. User Specifies nothing. All records are returned.

if any of these cases don't work for you then just test for those cases and display errors to user before building and running the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add a static `00:00:00` to the beginning variable and `23:59:59` to the end variable.

```
$sql_dateFrom= $sql_dateFrom." AND receivedDate='".$dateFrom." 00:00:00'";}

if(isset($dateTo) && $dateTo !=""){
    $sql_dateTo= $sql_dateTo." BETWEEN receivedDate='".$dateTo." 23:59:59'";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM visitdate WHERE id <> ''";
if (!empty($dateFrom)) {
    $query .= " AND receivedDate >= '$dateFrom'";
}
if (!empty($dateTo)) {
    $query .= " AND receivedDate <= '$dateTo'";
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Userid'];
}
```